# Invisible objects in the wireframe

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

3D is invisible with Wireframe enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wireframe mode, the object is actually supposed to be see-through. You also set it to transparency mode so that is why the lines aren't visible. On the top section, you will see the square behind a square like here :
[image]

and click on the square where I have pointed, your problem should be fixed.

cheerios,
Aster17

Comment: Also, Bituca, if you found this answer helpful, could you upvote this answer by clicking on the arrow above the  0. It would be really helpful.

Comment: hey Bituca, can you please upvote my answer If you found this answer useful.